# Issue with masonry + img srcset

Tags: javascript, html, masonry

I am using Masonry 4.2.2 (current version) by David DeSandro that is bundled with WordPress.

When I put images into it that have "srcset" and "sizes", it loads the proper size, BUT ALSO the maximum version -> a lot of wasted data. Happens in both Firefox and Chrome.

I made a simple set of two test pages (= deleted almost everything else), so it is simple to compare that behaviour:

1)
https://www.pastel.cz/temp/test_gallery_simple.php

Masonry initialization commented out, in Inspector I can confirm that only single size is loaded. For my browser window around 2 MB is transferred.

2)
https://www.pastel.cz/temp/test_gallery_masonry.php

Everything identical, only this time Masonry is properly initialized at the end. A lot of new image versions are loaded, for me it is over 7 MB of downloaded data.

Is there a way to Am I doing something wrong here? Or should I report it as a bug? Thank you for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

**Known issue**

I think I found the answer, it is a known bug of imagesLoaded - a library that is used together with masonry to react on lazy loaded images. The bug is open from 2015, probably not many people noticed the behaviour :)

https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/issues/175

**Workaround**

Anyway, since I specify the image sizes in advance in the HTML and thus the grid can be fully constructed during the init phase without loading the actual images, it seems that I can disable the imagesLoaded library and the issue vanishes.